# Managed C++ internal class?

Tags: .net, managed-c++

Is there a may to make a managed C++ class "internal"? I.E. What is the equivalent of "internal class" in managed C++?

Answer (score 1):

[It's `internal` but it was `public private` at one point in time](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=100163)